# Rules about Stevie

Tags: 7-wonders, 7-wonders-leaders

I am playing 7 wonders with [leaders](http://rprod.com/uploads/file/7WONDERS_LEADERS_RULES_EN_COLOR.pdf) and some other extensions to extensions. One of them includes [Stevie Wonder](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/99315/7-wonders-leaders-stevie).
Stevie does this:

> With his help, you can build a stage of your Wonder of the World; instead of paying the required number of resources, you pay the corresponding number of coins and slide Stevie under the appropriate stage face up.

But I have some questions about how Stevie interacts with other cards.

1. For example I'm playing with Rhodos B. First wonder stage costs 3 stones.  Before the first age I put in play the Leader Imhotep (allows you to build wonder stages with one less resource than needed). Before the second age, I put in play Stevie.

   - Does my first wonder stage cost 3 coins (as to stevie's rules)? Or 2 because I combine the effect of Imhotep with the effect of Stevie?
2. I'm in age 3. One of my neighbors played Stevie (age irrelevant). In the current round I play Guild of Courtesans (you can clone one leader from one of the neighbors for free). Let's say my next wonder stage costs 3 resources.

   - Can I clone Stevie?
   - If yes, does this mean I have to pay nothing for my next wonder stage or I still pay 3 coins as I would pay if I played Stevie myself?
   - Bonus: If I have to pay for Stevie and I have Imhotep in play (as in question 1) do I pay 2 or 3 coins?
3. I'm playing with [Abu Simbel](http://rprod.com/uploads/WONDERPACK_RULES_US.pdf) Side B. Before Age 1 I played one leader. Not important which one. Before age 2, I played Stevie, built my first wonder stage, paid 3 coins and sacrificed the leader I played before age 1. During Age 2 or 3 I build the second wonder stage.

   - Can I sacrifice Stevie?
   - If yes, do I get 6 points for this (2 * 3 coins I paid for Stevie)?
   - Bonus: What If I played Imhotep in the first age and Stevie only cost me 2 coins (this may not be valid depending on the answer for question 1), do I get 4 points only for sacrificing Stevie?

**Note**: Some of these scenarios have actually spawned during our games. Some Are just wild ideas based on the scenarios that actually happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly it would help to put all these as separate questions.  The first 2 specific examples are covered in the rules though under "interactions"

[image: picture of Stevie rules]

As for Abu Simbel.  The rules say he is placed face up in wonder when its built.  This would mean moving him afterwards to the side of the Abu Simbel where buried leaders are placed would be impossible as it would 'unbuild' the wonder.

As bonus info [this question](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1883858/amount-vp-cost-leaders-abu-simbel) there is this question on BGG where the designer covers issues of points awarded for Abu Simbel where the cost of Leader varies per age.  but as the 'cost' for Stevie can easily be calculated then that is the cost.

Comment: Ah. thanks for the picture. I didn't find that. This clears the fog. and I didn't want to put these as separate questions to not look spammy since thy are all tied together. Thanks for the "bonus" also. Apparently we've been playing this wrong.

Comment: To be honest when I read the question I came to conclusions that you would apply everything and get the best result as well.  Its when I looked up rules to back up by answer I got that instead!  There is also this ( https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1000597/does-stevie-interact-abu-simbel ) BGG answers which claims you cant put Stevie in Abu Simbel but to be me the timing of that doesn't make sense and its backed with with 'spoke to designer' rather than a post from Antoine Bauza himself.

Comment: actually thinking about it more it makes no sense that you can kill Stevie in Abu Simbal as he rules say to leave him face up.  You wouldn't then be able to move him to the section on the side of the wonder after he has been used.  I will edit answer to reflect this.

Comment: On [BGG](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/960053/abu-simbel-and-stevie), somebody said the designer says you can't bury Stevie.